# Using Array size to control Options Menu size

Tags: android, arrays, android-optionsmenu

I have an array of objects that changes in size as objects are added and removed.  There is an options menu on my activity that I would like to be able to choose which object you see the details of.

How do I pass the array details to the xml file that is controlling the menu, so I can run a for loop to add an item to the menu for each object in the array?

I would want to achieve this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    for(int i=0; i < bikes.size(); i==){
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bikes(i)"
        android:title=bikes(i).getName()></item>
    }

</menu>
```

But of course I'm in xml, not java.  How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: provide your code!

Comment: Hi, I don't really have code yet, as I don't know how it's done.  I have an array called bikes of type bike.  I  have a menu.xml file that needs to reference that array.  I'm asking how I do that.

Edited code in above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following code :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        for(int i=0; i < bikes.size(); i++){

          String bikeModelMenu = bikes.get(i).model;
          menu.add(0, i, 0, bikeModelMenu).setShortcut('3', 'c');

        }


        return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {           

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:
        // code for first select
        return true;


    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have some errors.  Trying to correct them, the closest I get is - menu.add(0, 0, ($ID), bikes.get(i).make.setShortcut('3', 'c')); but $ID says it can't resolve symbol and can't resolve method setShortcut?

Comment: A bit more digging and I got a working line - menu.add(0, i, 0, bikeMakeMenu).setShortcut('3', 'c');

Comment: The menu will only load in once I've added items, leave and come back to the activity.  How do I get it to update as a bike is added?  Can I call the method manually?

Comment: @AndyCr15 what is your problem now?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help so far. I'm asking now, how can I get it to recreate the menu when a new bike is added to the array? I can call the method, but (Menu menu) won't work of course.

Comment: I'm new to this, but I've submitted the correct code in your original answer, so I assume I can then mark it correct?

Comment: @AndyCr15 if it worked and helped you, sure yes, just to help others.

Comment: So anyone with any ideas how I can make it recreate the options menu, without recreating the whole activity?

Comment: @AndyCr15 it's hard because you override two method after implemment their own class... also you can try to use service